# Pitting two Blackjack bots against each other

Tags: c#, programming-challenge, random, playing-cards, ai

I'm taking part in this Daily Challenge on http://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/29zut0/772014_challenge_170_easy_blackjack_checker/

Basically, you have to develop a program that runs two blackjack players and outputs the winner, the user has no input on the player's choices - basically it's all AI based. I'm using the CASE statements to check for the card that the player receives, but I find it really inefficient, there's too much code for such a small program - especially when I compare it with others on the post.

Could anyone help me shorten the code, maybe suggest an alternative to the CASES?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BlackJack_Winner
{
    class Program
    {
        //Variables
        static Random randomRunner = new Random();
        static int randOut, player1Count, player2count;


        //Player 2's method, contains algorithm to calculate their hand
        public static void player2Cases()
        {
            //Loop to give the player two cards
            for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++)
            {

                randOut = randomRunner.Next(1, 11);
                switch (randOut)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Console.WriteLine("Player 2 has an ACE");
                        if (player2count <= 10) //If player 2's hand is less than or equal to 10, then the player classes the ACE as an 11
                        {
                            player2count = player2count + 11;
                        }
                        else //If player2's hand is higher than 10, then they class the ACE as a 1
                        {
                            player2count = player2count + 1;
                        }
                        break;
                    case 2: //From here on out, the cases each add the amount, from the card that the player drew.
                        Console.WriteLine("Player 2 has a 2");
                        player2count = player2count + 2;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Console.WriteLine("Player 2 has a 3");
                        player2count = player2count + 3;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        Console.WriteLine("Player 2 has a 4");
                        player2count = player2count + 4;
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        Console.WriteLine("Player 2 has a 5");
                        player2count = player2count + 5;
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        Console.WriteLine("Player 2 has a 6");
                        player2count = player2count + 6;
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        Console.WriteLine("Player 2 has a 7");
                        player2count = player2count + 7;
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        Console.WriteLine("Player 2 has an 8");
                        player2count = player2count + 8;
                        break;
                    case 9:
                        Console.WriteLine("Player 2 has a 9");
                        player2count = player2count + 9;
                        break;
                    case 10:
                        Console.WriteLine("Player 2 has a 10");
                        player2count = player2count + 10;
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("");
                        break;

                }
                if (i == 1) //Prints out the player's final hand when both cards have been drawn
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(player2count);
                }

            }


        }


        //Player 1's method, contains algorithm to calculate their hand
        public static void player1Cases()
        {
            //Loop to draw the player just two cards, as per standard BlackJack game
            for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++ )
            {

                randOut = randomRunner.Next(1, 11);//random number between 1 and 11
                switch (randOut)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Console.WriteLine("Player 1 has an ACE");
                        if(player1Count <= 10)
                        {
                            player1Count = player1Count + 11;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            player1Count = player1Count + 1;
                        }
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Console.WriteLine("Player 1 has a 2");
                        player1Count = player1Count + 2;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Console.WriteLine("Player 1 has a 3");
                        player1Count = player1Count + 3;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        Console.WriteLine("Player 1 has a 4");
                        player1Count = player1Count + 4;
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        Console.WriteLine("Player 1 has a 5");
                        player1Count = player1Count + 5;
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        Console.WriteLine("Player 1 has a 6");
                        player1Count = player1Count + 6;
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        Console.WriteLine("Player 1 has a 7");
                        player1Count = player1Count + 7;
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        Console.WriteLine("Player 1 has an 8");
                        player1Count = player1Count + 8;
                        break;
                    case 9:
                        Console.WriteLine("Player 1 has a 9");
                        player1Count = player1Count + 9;
                        break;
                    case 10:
                        Console.WriteLine("Player 1 has a 10");
                        player1Count = player1Count + 10;
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("");
                        break;

                }
                if(i == 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(player1Count);
                }


            }

        }

        //Main method
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Calls methods
            player1Cases();
            player2Cases();

            if(player1Count < player2count)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Player 1 wins!");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Player 2 wins!");
            }

            //Waits for user input
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can shorten switch to

```
            randOut = randomRunner.Next(1, 11);
            if (randOut == 1 && player2count <= 10)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Player 2 has ACE");
                player2count += 11;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Player 2 has {0}", randOut == 1? "ACE" : randOut.ToString());
                player2count += randOut;
            }
```

edit: you can also remove duplicated methods (whole class)

```
class Program
{
    private static readonly Random randomRunner = new Random();

    public static int drawCard(string playerName)
    {
        var playerCount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++)
        {
            var randOut = randomRunner.Next(1, 11);
            if (randOut == 1 && playerCount <= 10)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} has ACE", playerName);
                playerCount += 11;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} has {1}", playerName, randOut == 1? "ACE" : randOut.ToString());
                playerCount += randOut;
            }

        }
        Console.WriteLine(playerCount);
        return playerCount;
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        var player1Count = drawCard("Player 1");
        var player2Count = drawCard("Player 2");

        if (player1Count < player2Count)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Player 1 wins!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Player 2 wins!");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: So rid of all of the CASE statements and replace them with IF-ELSE?

Comment: I could have thought of that, I'm looking for ways to shorten the code, that of which won't do much.

Comment: Then why didn't you think of that?  It shortens it greatly.

Comment: Could you please annotate some parts of this, a lot of the procedures are new to me.

Comment: @DunderMifflin11 I think looking at the docs for [`String.Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [the ternary conditional](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) will clear up a lot of your questions.